# Publish github artifact on push to main without creating release

Tags: github, github-actions, release, continuous-deployment

I want to build a C dynamic lib in my Github project every time I push to main branch, and make the lib permanently available to download, each tagged with the commit hash, like libfoo-d3f34839eac.so. I've tried

- Github packages, but that doesn't support C dynamic libs
- releases, but they require a tag, and I don't want to tag every commit on my branch. I *could* make one large dynamic super-release that I push everything to, but that's ugly
- Github Actions build artifacts, but those only last 90 days and aren't intended to be publicly consumable

I want to keep it all within Github so S3 isn't an option.

Comment: You may push those directly to your repo under a `release` directory.

Comment: @Azeem thanks but I don't want to check binaries into git

Comment: @Azeem but what I might do is create another repo whose only purpose is to store the build artifacts, and push to that

Comment: Seems like S3 is the only option - you may want to re-consider it since GitHub is now having daily outages.

Comment: @joel: Yes, a separate repo is another alternative if you don't want to push to the same repo.